# != operator doesn't seem to be working when comparing a variable to an integer

Tags: java, operator-keyword

All I'm trying to do is create a validation loop if the user enters anything other than "1" or "2"... but when I test the program, regardless of what number I entered (including 1 and 2), the validation loop prompts. Am I blind?? I can't see what's wrong with this syntax.

```
public static int getValidShiftNbr(String msg)
  {
    int nbr = IR4.getInteger(msg);
    while ((nbr != 1) || (nbr != 2))  <===================================
    {
      System.err.println("Error: Please enter either 1 (for day shift) or 2 (for night shift)");
      nbr = IR4.getInteger(msg);
    }
    return nbr;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an OR `||` it only needs to satisfy one of the conditions, in your case if you enter `1` OR `2` the condition will be `true`.

You want to use the AND `&&` operator to make sure it neither of them, as shown below:

`while ((nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2))`

**OR**

`while (!((nbr == 1) || (nbr == 2)))`

Here the condition will be `true` for any number other than `1` and `2`

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel quite dumb. I guess I was putting it into English... "if the number isn't 1 OR 2.."

Comment: @llamagish "number isn't 1 OR 2" means `!(nbr == 1 || nbr == 2)` which is equivalent to `(!(nbr == 1)) && (!(nbr == 2))` and also `nbr != 1 && nbr != 2`, by De Morgan's Laws. Hope that clears up the logical confusion

Answer (score 2):

in your code:

if (nbr == 1); what happen is

```
nbr != 1 => false
nbr != 2 => true
```

(false) || (true) => **true** since it is OR operator

to achieve what you want is using a **AND** operator

**`(nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2)`**

1) if (nbr == 1)

```
(nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2) // false AND true => false
```

2) if (nbr == 2)

```
 (nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2) // true AND false => false
```

3) if (nbr == 3)

```
(nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2) // true AND true => true
```

Answer (score 1):

!= is working, || (which is or) is also working 
all values of nbr will be != to 1 OR THEY WILL BE != to 2  (possibly both)

btw: nbr is an inferior variable name--  better names would be number or shift

btw: I suggest using n or N or d or D the identify the shift because the computer should do the work, instead of the human

your code should be

while ((nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2))

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
while ((nbr != 1) || (nbr != 2))
```

It will ***always*** be true because whatever input you give will always trigger either `(nbr != 1)` or `(nbr != 2)`

If you only want the user to input only 1 or 2:

```
while ((nbr != 1) && (nbr != 2))
```

**Or**

```
while (!((nbr == 1) || (nbr == 2)))
```